# How can I open a file and notify when it is closed in Java?

Tags: java, file, system, desktop, pid

My question is clear I think, is it possible to open a file automatically according to its extension then when it's closed get notify?

I try to open file with this way:

```
File f = new File(url);
Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
```

But I can't get notification when the file closed, is there any alternative for that?

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: You could poll it and check if it's being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to look at [WatchService API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

> The WatchService API is designed for applications that need to be
>   notified about file change events.

You can also check if your file is closed or not like this using Apache:

```
boolean open = false;
try
{
  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.touch(myFile);
  open = true;
}
catch
{   
    open = false;
}

if(open == false){
    // Show notification message.
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain how WatchService can be used to answer the question.  Also, your entire code block can be written as `if (!FileUtils.touch(myFile))`.

Comment: @Ozi:- Yes it returns a void. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#touch(java.io.File)